# how should I process a set of async commands driven by a loop?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, coffeescript

Say I want to insert a group of Store records into the database and call a callback when they are *all* complete:

```
insertStores = (db, stores, callback) ->
  sql = ""
  processed = 0
  for store in stores
    do (store) ->
      # build sql
      sql = "some built sql goes here" 

      processQuery(db, sql, ->
        ++processed
        if processed >= stores.length
          callback?()
      )
```

I'm wondering if there's a more readable way to do this that will get rid of the `processed` variable. It's important that all inserts get processed before the callback is fired. I don't want to bring in any async to sync libraries. This is for a script, not an application.

Is there a better way to do this in coffeescript? I'm wondering if there's an elegant coffee-ish solution that I'm not aware of.

Comment: I understand that you want to find a simple coffee-ish way. I'm afraid there is no way (yet), maybe some day with generators of ES6. But BTW isn't it possible to concat the SQL an do a bulk insert? Is this MySQL? And I wouldn't bother using `async` or `Seq` when doing server-side programming. It's more readable to other node.js programmers than detecting what you want to achieve with constructs like `if i == stores.length - 1`.

Comment: "But BTW isn't it possible to concat the SQL an do a bulk insert?" yes, but I can just as easily ask this question for other async operations that don't concatenate well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you specifically need a CoffeeScript way of doing this? I think the [Async package](https://www.npmjs.org/package/async) would be a good thing to use. It has a number of functions to let you run asynchronous tasks in series or parallel and get a single callback when everything is finished.

Comment: Well, yeah, that is what I asked for. I'm looking for a native solution. I want to know if there is a better way to do this without bringing in a library.